Error in linux (bedrock linux based on cachyos/Arch with an ubuntu strata) where there is an issue with finding a file (unable to find file (ENOENT) )
Context:
I am in a bedrock Linux virtual machine and I am attempting to install an application from Ubuntu. I am trying to install Lokinet service. I am greatly dependent on arch Linux (I use CachyOS which is arch based with some performance tweaks but other than that, they are identical) but this service is only supported for Debian and Ubuntu + Deb/Ubuntu based distros.
The problem:
I ran the commands found in this guide but ran into errors which the very very kind bedrock Linux developer helped me through on Reddit
the developer modified the commands and instructed that I run the following:

sudo strat ubuntu curl -so /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/oxen.gpg https://deb.oxen.io/pub.gpg


and

echo "deb https://deb.oxen.io $(strat ubuntu lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /bedrock/strata/ubuntu/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oxen.list


The first command seemed to have worked as it gave me a tilda output, not sure if it actually did anything though, but the second command gives me the following output:
strat: could not run
    lsb_release
from stratum
    ubuntu
due to: unable to find file (ENOENT)
deb https://deb.oxen.io  main

~

As this seems more like a directories issue than it is with bedrock itself, I decided that coming here would be best for this type of question.
(The reason I am using bedrock Linux is so that I can have the benefits of other distros whilst staying on my preferred Arch or Gentoo distributions. 
It is much easier to just hijack an existing system and just throw the other parts I want in, like say the dinit init system from artix.)

You need to install the lsb-release package in the Ubuntu stratum:
strat ubuntu apt install lsb-release

You’ll then be able to run the failing command again.
